# CC in Marketing Cloud - Send All Campaign Members the same Email - all in CC ? (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: journeybuilder, automationstudio

We're trying to automate Client Meeting Notes sent from Marketing Cloud without leaving the CRM;

- The recipients are SF **Campaign Members** who constitute the Key Stakeholders of the meeting.
- An automation should run once a day to pick up the Campaign Members and the notes left on a field in Salesforce CRM which will be injected to the email
- The challenge: 'Reply-All' option.

Without the Reply-All option, there are a few ways to achieve this,

e.g.

- Automation Studio with or without Journey builder
- or even Triggered sends.

So far we thought of two solutions:

1. Intuitively, this will be 1 email send to CC. Is this possible?
2. When we started thinking of workarounds - the "Reply-To" address could represent an email group.
   But the group should be dynamic - as we add more Campaign Members.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but requires a workaround.
The CC/BCC functionality (JB / Automation Studio) only accepts direct email addresses typed in, or AmpScript - limited to 250 characters - which means we don't have enough characters to loop.

We have achieved this in a few steps:
 1. Contact support to enable the CC option.
 2. Enumerate (in SF) the Campaign members from 1 to N on a new field called TeamMemberNum 
 3. Use the following AmpScript on each recipient to add as CC:

```
%%=v(lookup('DE-Name', 'email' ,'TeamMemberNum', "1"))=%%
%%=v(lookup('DE-Name', 'email' ,'TeamMemberNum', "2"))=%%
%%=v(lookup('DE-Name', 'email' ,'TeamMemberNum', "3"))=%%
```

etc. (according to the max number of CCs you need)

We use the TeamMemberNum (And not CampaignMemberID) because we need to know the value in advance - when we define the Email Send Activity - to add it in CC.

4. Use SQL Query Activity to update the DE with the CampaignMembers

More on CC/BCC limitations here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_select_audience.htm&type=5